# Unable to Extract token from JSON Response using Almofire in swift4

Tags: ios, json, swift4

Can some one help me to how to extract token from one of my web services request using almofire in swift4. I want to store token in one of the variable. below I have posted the JSON response from my web service. Also I have posted the Code I have written in swift4. I am newbie to Swift4 so please let me know if you need additional information to answer my question. I have highlighted the code line in bold and commented where I am getting error. May be I am not reading JSON data correctly. I am newbie to JSON arrays and objects. Please help me with code sample.

JSON Response:

> Successfully got data {
>       data =     {
>           token = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJVc2VySWQiOiJiODcwY2Q4My0zZDMzLTQ1ODgtYmZlMi00MzQ0ODQ4ZmJiOGMiLCJDb250YWN0SWQiOiJiODU4NTAyYy1lZGM2LTRlY2QtYTk0ZC1kMjEwNmI3YjZlMmQiLCJuYmYiOjE1Njk4Mjk1OTAsImV4cCI6MTU2OTgzNjc5MCwiaWF0IjoxNTY5ODI5NTkwfQ.LO2Z4n0IRYaaJM6Pmp8pLeo3alDPmioaAF4ces2K-9M";
>       };
>       message = "";
>       status = Success; }

I can able to extract the status from above JSON Response but I am not able to extract the token Below is my swift4 code.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController{
let URL_USER_LOGIN = "some url"
  let defaultValues = UserDefaults.standard

@IBOutlet weak var labelMessage: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldUserName: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldPassword: UITextField!

    @IBAction func buttonLogin(_ sender: Any) {

let parameters: Parameters=[
            "username":textFieldUserName.text!,
            "password":textFieldPassword.text!
        ]


Alamofire.request(URL_USER_LOGIN, method: .post,parameters: parameters,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON
            {

                response in
let jsonData = response.result.value as? NSDictionary
let status = jsonData? ["status"] as! String

// when I use **tokendata = jsonData? ["token"] as! String**   I am getting Error Please help me with code fixes 

if status == "Success" {

let profileViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewcontroller") as! ProfileViewController
                        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(profileViewController, animated: true)


                        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

                    }else{
                        //error message in case of invalid credential
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Email or Passowrd is Not matching", preferredStyle: .alert)
                        let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style:.default, handler: nil)
                        alert.addAction(ok)
                        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        //self.labelMessage.text = "Invalid username or password"
                    }
                }
        }


 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: " ", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: navigationController, action: nil)
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton

        if defaultValues.string(forKey: "username") != nil{
            let profileViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewcontroller") as! ProfileViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(profileViewController, animated: true)

        }
    }

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    }
```

Comment: Please **read** the JSON. On the same level as the key `status` there is a key `data`. The token is inside that nested dictionary. And don’t use `NS...` collection types in Swift. Use native types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to modify your `JSON` response. because it is not well formated. your `JSON` should be like following.

```
{
  "status" : "Success",
  "message" : "your message",
  "data":{"token" : "your_token"}
}
```

You are using `SwiftyJSON`. so you can parse your value with `SwiftyJSON` like following

```
let json = try JSON(data: response.data)

let status = json["status"].stringValue

let message = json["message"].stringValue 

let data = json["data"].dictionaryValue

let token = data["token"]?.stringValue
```

Comment: i Jakir Thanks unfortunately I don't have control on JSON format. can you pl;ease guide me how can I modify my code with existing JSON format